# Get function return value

Tags: static-analysis, dynamic-analysis

Any idea for more ways to get return value?
(No hooks, no hw/memory breakpoints, no call functions).
thx :)

I tried to find a dword maybe that hold the function return, but I didn't find it.

I'm trying to create an API.

Comment: There is often no memory involved. Usually the return value is passed ina register, which depends on your architecture. In any serious szenario you can not just read a memory location for a return value.

Comment: @Devolus x86, so how should i get return value, or the value himself without the methods i mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Every assembly architecture has it's own [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), which defines how arguments are passed to a function, and how they are returned. You need to identify your relevant calling conventions and act accordingly.

For example, in `ARM` assembly architecture, the register `R0` holds the return value.

Comment: My function is a "thiscall", calling from class, but the problem is that, one of the parameters are dynamic(is a structure with dynamic values), and i can't find who create him.